# temporal removal on depth result in ghostly image

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to do temporarl removal on depth image, and I'm getting a ghosty image as shown in the video below

Single Image:

[image]

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HBlpuihzks

and here is the code:

```
   while (key != 'q') {

        if (zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == ERROR_CODE::SUCCESS) {

            zed.retrieveImage(depth_image_zed_display, VIEW::DEPTH, MEM::CPU, new_image_size);

            zed.retrieveMeasure(depth_image_zed, MEASURE::DEPTH, MEM::CPU, new_image_size);
            cv::Mat dst;
            //cv::boxFilter(depth_image_ocv_display, dst, -1, cv::Size(1, 1));

            cv::Mat result;
            double factor = 0.5;
            cv::addWeighted(depth_image_ocv, 1.0 - factor, last_image, factor, 0.0, result);
            last_image = result;


            cv::imshow("dep", depth_image_ocv_display);


            cv::Mat ucharMat, ucharMatScaled;
            result.convertTo(result, CV_8UC1);
            // scale values from 0..1 to 0..255
            result.convertTo(ucharMatScaled, CV_8UC1, 255, 0);
            cv::imshow("filtered_ dep", ucharMatScaled);


            // Handle key event
            key = cv::waitKey(10);
        }
    }
```

Updated Code:

```
while (key != 'q') {

        if (zed.grab(runtime_parameters) == ERROR_CODE::SUCCESS) {
             
            zed.retrieveImage(depth_image_zed_display, VIEW::DEPTH, MEM::CPU, new_image_size);

            zed.retrieveMeasure(depth_image_zed, MEASURE::DEPTH, MEM::CPU, new_image_size);
           
          /*
           cv::Mat dst;
           cv::boxFilter(depth_image_ocv, dst, -1, cv::Size(1, 1));

           */

           
        cv::Mat cpy_depth = depth_image_ocv.clone();
        cv::Mat result;
        double factor = 0.8;
        cv::addWeighted(cpy_depth, 1.0 - factor, last_image, factor, 0.0, result);
        last_image = result.clone();
    

        cv::imshow("dep", depth_image_ocv_display);
        cv::Mat final_depth;
        final_depth = result.clone();

        cv::Mat ucharMatScaled;
        final_depth.convertTo(ucharMatScaled, CV_8UC1, 0, 255);
        cv::imshow("filtered_ dep", ucharMatScaled);

            // Handle key event
            key = cv::waitKey(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `depth_image_ocv` initialized and what's its type?

Comment: @Thomas Mat depth_image_zed(new_width, new_height, MAT_TYPE::F32_C1);
    cv::Mat depth_image_ocv = slMat2cvMat(depth_image_zed);

Comment: @Thomas I use Zed Camera API https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/opencv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        cv::addWeighted(depth_image_ocv, 1.0 - factor, last_image, factor, 0.0, result);
```

The above line only works correctly if `depth_image_ocv` and `last_image` matrices are both floating-point type (`F32_C1`). However, look here:

```
        last_image = result;
```

This doesn't make a copy of `result` into `last_image`; it [only copies a reference](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aed1f81fe7efaacc2bd95149cdfa34302), so `last_image` and `result` are the *same* matrix from here on out.

That matrix is subsequently clobbered by converting it to byte type:

```
        result.convertTo(result, CV_8UC1);
```

So this doesn't just affect `result`, but `last_image` too. Use [`clone`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#adff2ea98da45eae0833e73582dd4a660) or [`copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77) instead of `operator=` to get an actual copy of an OpenCV matrix.

(It's bad API design that goes contrary to C++ idioms, but it probably won't ever be fixed.)

Comment: thanks for that notice, +1, I updated the code, but still I get ghosty image

Comment: I even used             cv::accumulateWeighted(depth_image_ocv, accumulator, 0.5);
Instead of the AddWeighted, I still get ghosty image

Comment: I wanna do temporarily removal for the depth image, what I get right now with your fix is a ghostly image that the filter image gets darker and more darker until it's fully dark.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `result.convertTo(result, CV_8UC1);`
You are converting your float image to a unsigned char image, resulting in all pixel values being either 0 or 1. Only afterwars you scale them up, resulting in an image with pixel values either 0 or 255.

Comment: so I just removed the line, what else should be done, +1

Comment: I wanna do temporarily removal for the depth image, what I get right now with your fix is a ghostly image that the filter image gets darker and more darker until it's fully dark.

Comment: Where do last_image and depth_image_ocv come from? In your code i don't see how they are initialized

Comment: depth_image_ocv  comes from Zed SDK, last_image is just a matrix initialized to zeros with the size of depth image

Comment: Do you always get to see the current frame if you set factor to 0 ? How does it look with a small value for factor, e.g. 0.2?

Comment: When I set it to 0, I don't see current frame, instead black lines that the image gets faded to black at the end over time. with small values the same result.

Comment: here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HBlpuihzks